# Datepicker for React-Strap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using `react-strap` npm package to use Bootstrap 4 components in my React app.

When I try to add the datepicker `react-bootstrap-date-picker`

```
npm install --save react-bootstrap-date-picker
```

then try to use it in my component:

```
var DatePicker = require("react-bootstrap-date-picker");
```

I get the error

> Error in ./~/react-bootstrap-date-picker/lib/index.js
>
> Module not found: 'react-bootstrap/lib/Button' in C:\Users\y\Desktop\Code\test\node_modules\react-bootstrap-date-picker\lib
>
> @ ./~/react-bootstrap-date-picker/lib/index.js 15:14-51

Is this because `react-bootstrap-date-picker` is not compatible with `react-strap`? In this case, which npm packages should I install for bootstrap 4 components so that the datepicker module can work?

Answer (score 9):

react-bootstrap-date-picker is using react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap depends on bootstrap3. reactstrap is for bootstrap4 That is why it doesnt work.

You can use [react-widgets DateTimePicker](https://jquense.github.io/react-widgets/api/DateTimePicker/) instead.

Answer (score 3):

You have now available [`reactstrap-date-picker`](https://github.com/afialapis/reactstrap-date-picker), which is heavily based on `react-bootstrap-date-picker`, but ready  for the `reactstrap` world.

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of the library.

Although still in first 0.* versions, I'm using it successfully on my projects and, as soon as I receive feedback enough, it'll be 1.0 and considered production-ready.

Comment: reactstrap-date-picker is not working with latest reactstrap version

Comment: @Laxminarayan, looks like we have the same issue.

Comment: reactstrap-date-picker should work also with latest Reactstrap. If not working for you, don't hesitate to add an issue: https://github.com/afialapis/reactstrap-date-picker/issues. Thanks!